# Python eve ?where query returns empty result

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

I have a mongo collection called Case which has the following records:

```
{
    _updated: "Tue, 26 Jul 2016 10:47:34 GMT",
    user_id: "ronaldo",
    client: "webapp",
    _links: {
        self: {
            href: "case/57972a253d73f156b5427ac3",
            title: "case"
        }
    },
    _created: "Tue, 26 Jul 2016 09:15:17 GMT",
    _id: "57972a253d73f156b5427ac3",
    _etag: "e85847955b97c2a339628071397ab4cafd959062"
},
{
    _updated: "Tue, 26 Jul 2016 09:20:50 GMT",
    user_id: "578ca6e4daaf452467ffa9f2",
    client: "webapp",
    _links: {
        self: {
            href: "case/57972b723d73f156b5427ac4",
            title: "case"
        }
    },
    _created: "Tue, 26 Jul 2016 09:20:50 GMT",
    _id: "57972b723d73f156b5427ac4",
    _etag: "6a6066ed62c91d0f79bbf3a362b567f8e7710f63"
}
```

The following query returns data correctly:

```
http://localhost:8000/case?where={"user_id":"ronaldo"}
```

**whereas the following query returns empty result set:**

```
http://localhost:8000/case?where={"user_id":"578ca6e4daaf452467ffa9f2"}
```

> Please note that If I do the query directly in mongo, it works:
>
> ```
> db.case.find({user_id: "578ca6e4daaf452467ffa9f2"})
> ```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `user_id` can sometimes contain objectid-like strings. Try setting `query_objectid_as_string` in your resource settings. Quoting the [docs](http://python-eve.org/config):

> When [query_objectid_as_string is] enabled the Mongo parser will avoid automatically casting electable strings to ObjectIds. This can be useful in those rare occurrences where you have string fields in the database whose values can actually be casted to ObjectId values, but shouldn’t. It effects queries (?where=) and parsing of payloads. Defaults to False.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! Thanks a million!

Comment: with query_objectid_as_string = True,  http://localhost:8000/case/578ca6e4daaf452467ffa9f2 does not work anymore.